# Migrating development environment to use CMake + Git

Tags: c++, git, cmake, cross-platform, development-environment

Currently I am trying to learn best practice for cross platform development to allow better productivity in future projects. I started out with a basic setup using the unix terminal on both OS X and linux. I then used a combination of a Cygwin environment with MinGW GCC compiler on windows. Everything was then managed from a universal makefile (see below) that would use rsync as a basic form of versioning that linked to a central repository.

My current project directory structure is:

```
project_root
  include
  src
    makefile
  platform
    win
      build
        resources (Media)
        shaders (GLSL Shaders)
      include (platform specific include)
      lib (platform specific libraries)
      object
    mac
      build
        resources
        shaders
      include
      lib
      object
  resources
  shaders
```

and the makefile looks like:

```
PROJECT_NAME := craft


UNAME := $(shell uname)

OS_TYPE     := WINDOWS
EXE         := .exe
DIR         := win
LDFLAG      := -Wall -g -std=c++11 -mwindows -static -L../platform/$(DIR)/lib -lstdc++ -lgdi32 -lglew -lglfw3 -lopengl32
CXXINCLUDE  := -I../platform/$(DIR)/include
LD          := i686-w64-mingw32-gcc
CXX         := i686-w64-mingw32-gcc

ifeq ($(UNAME), Darwin)
OS_TYPE     := MACINTOSH
EXE         := 
DIR         := mac
LDFLAG      := -Wall -g -std=c++11 -L../platform/$(DIR)/lib -lstdc++ -lglfw3 -framework Cocoa -framework OpenGL -framework IOKit -framework CoreVideo
CXXINCLUDE  := -I../platform/$(DIR)/include
LD          := clang
CXX         := clang
endif

CXXFLAG     := -Wall -g -I../include
CU          := nvcc
CPP_FILES   := $(wildcard *.cpp)
OBJ_FILES   := $(CPP_FILES:.cpp=.o)

all: build

build: $(OBJ_FILES)
    $(LD) -o ../platform/$(DIR)/build/$@$(EXE) $(addprefix ../platform/$(DIR)/object/, $^) $(LDFLAG)

%.o: %.cpp
    $(CXX) -o ../platform/$(DIR)/object/$@ -c $< $(CXXFLAG) $(CXXINCLUDE)

platform:
    echo $(OS_TYPE)

clean: clobject
    rm -rf ../platform/$(DIR)/build/build$(EXE)

clobject:
    rm -rf ../platform/$(DIR)/object/*.o

resources:
    rsync -va --delete ../resources ../platform/$(DIR)/build/

shaders:
    rsync -va --delete ../shaders ../platform/$(DIR)/build/

run:
    ../platform/$(DIR)/build/build$(EXE)

send:
    rsync -va --delete $(DEV)/$(PROJECT_NAME) $(DEV_MASTER)

get:
    rsync -va --delete $(DEV_MASTER)/$(PROJECT_NAME) $(DEV)
```

This is fine for any basic projects but it does have issues and I would like for example to use MSVC within windows rather than GCC. I would really appreciate any advice on environment setups and workflows/tools to use?

Preferably I would like:

- To use native compilers for each system (Win: MSVC, Mac: Clang, Lin: GCC).
- A basic CMake setup that would work with my current file structure, is this possible?
- Work from one command shell that can run Git (instead of rsync), CMake and use the generated file to build an executable. Preferably using unix commands rather than DOS.

This is all rather simple when using *nix based systems but with windows for example, could I use Git Bash without using Visual Studio Command Prompt to run a makefile/ninja that uses cl.exe? Or would it be better to just use a .vcprog?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes this is very much doable and actually pretty straight forward.

Everything you want should be covered by the basic cmake examples.

A note on your build folders:
Those should not be part of your source tree. Instead you should copy all resource files from a location in your source tree to your build folder.

Comment: I've almost converted it now, I understand that platform if statements are still necessary. It's easy when you get used to the find_package/libraries commands. I've also taken the build directory out of the src which makes it cleaner for pushing to github, cheers.